# How to solve this diophantine equation ($4$ variables)?

Tags: number-theory

$$4(9k^4-l^4)=9m^4-n^4$$

Well, it seems a little bit harder than finding Pythagorean triples. Right now I have no idea where to actually start so any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You could factor the difference of squares as one idea to get started.  Another thought is to consider what are some numbers of the form $9x^4-y^4$?  Hope that helps some.

Comment: Factorize it and start analyzing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We show **by descent** that $k=l=m=n=0$ is the only solution.

Modulo $5$, the left-hand side is congruent to $k^4+l^4$, while the right-hand side is congruent to $-(m^4+n^4)$.

Any fourth power is congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $5$. So the sum of two fourth powers is congruent to $0$, $1$, or $2$.

In particular, the sum of two fourth powers is congruent to the negative of a sum of two fourth powers only if both sums are divisible by $5$. And this only happens if $k$, $l$, $m$, and $n$ are all divisible by $5$.

So if $(k,l,m,n)$ is a solution, then so is $(k/5,l/5,m/5,n/5)$. Continue. We conclude that $k$, $l$, $m$, and $n$ are divisible by arbitrarily high powers of $5$, so are all $0$.

**Remark:** The classical Frmat-style descent argument can be reworded. Suppose that there is a solution $(k,l,m,n)$ with not all the variables equal to $0$. Then there is a solution with $|k|+|l|+|m|+|n|$ positive and as small as possible. Use the above argument to conclude that $(k/5,l/5,m/5,n/5)$ is an integer solution. This contradicts the minimality of $|k|+|l|+|m|+|n|$. Or else we can reword things so as to use standard mathematical induction terminology.

Comment: Suppose (k,l,m,n) is a solution and $k$, $l$, $m$, $n$ are not zero (or at least some of them aren't). By dividing them, they'll eventually become fractions, still, they'll be able to satisfy the equation so I don't get the point of sorting the nonzero solutions out. Could you please elaborate on the last part?

Comment: We are looking for **integer** solutions $(k,l,m,n)$. We have shown that for any such solution, $k/5,l/5,m/5,n/5$ are integers. Applying the result again to $k/5,l/5,m/5,n/5$, we conclude that these are divisible by $5$, so $k,l,m,n$ are all divisible by $5^2$. Continuing, we find that $k,l,m,n$ are all divisible by $5^3$. Indeed they are divisible by all powers of $5$, so can only be integers if they are all $0$.

Comment: Now it's clear, thank you for your help.